# Change text colour in custom Toolbar

Tags: android, xml

By default, my Action Bar has white text.

I have a View that uses a custom Toolbar, but the text shows up black instead.

I can't see what the issue is. I'm guessing it's do to with inheritance?

Snippet from `activity_stories.xml`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
       android:id="@+id/tabs"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:tabMode="fixed"
       app:tabGravity="fill"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

My `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
   android:supportsRtl="true"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

   <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity android:name=".StoriesActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
   <activity android:name=".StoryBodyActivity"></activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Could you check my answer ?Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to change `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />` to `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />`

Answer (score 0):

**1.set `android:textColorPrimary` and `android:textColorPrimaryInverse` in styles**

**2.set in `Toolbar`**

Try this .

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    app:theme="@style/yourToolbar" />


 <style name="yourToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
     <!-- android:textColorPrimary is the  color of the title text
      in the Toolbar, in the Theme.AppCompat theme:  -->
     <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/my_color</item>

     <!-- android:textColorPrimaryInverse is the  color of the title
      text in the Toolbar, in the Theme.AppCompat.Light theme:  -->
     <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/my_color</item>
</style>
```